# Why this script blocking browsing of any website after running it?

Tags: 16.04, iptables

i found this script here

[How to stop the synattack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869205/how-to-stop-the-synattack)

```
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.05

echo "Loading Protect rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
EXTIF="ens3"
EXTIP1="41.61.59.103"
EXTIMESENTER=10

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
# Otherwise, I can not seem to delete it later on
$IPTABLES -F add-to-connlimit-list
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z

echo "...load xt_recent..."
modprobe -r xt_recent
modprobe xt_recent ip_list_tot=5000 ip_pkt_list_tot=128
echo "...load list limitation..."
#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# add-to-connlimit-list
# To many connections from an IP address has been detected.
$IPTABLES -N add-to-connlimit-list
$IPTABLES -A add-to-connlimit-list -m recent --set --name BADGUY_CONN
$IPTABLES -A add-to-connlimit-list -j DROP
echo "...Accept incomming traffic..."

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j REJECT

# Just DROP invalid packets.
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP


# external interface, from any source, for any remaining ICMP traffic is valid
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p ICMP -s $UNIVERSE -j DROP

#allow TcpPorts
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 432000 --name BADGUY_CONN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above $EXTIMESENTER -j add-to-connlimit-list

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state NEW -p tcp -j ACCEPT

echo "...protect TcpPorts..."


# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in. i moved it here to drop the attacker current connectivety as you told me
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "...Allow any related traffic..."



# O.K. at this point, we will DROP the packet, however some will be dropped without logging just to make the log file
# less cluttered.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p udp -m multiport --dport 33434:33448 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m multiport --dport 23,2323 -j DROP

#this rule may not needed
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j DROP

echo Protect rule set version $FWVER done.
```

but when i run this script on my ubuntu machine i am unable to browse any website from the browsers

any idea why ?

Comment: It is not recommended to just execute scripts from the Internet without knowing really well how they work and what they do. For instance, in this script, the name of the interface is `ens3`. Is that also the name of your interface?

Comment: Interface Name and Public IP most likely don't match.

Answer (score 2):

> when i run this script on my ubuntu machine i am unable to browse any
>   website from the browsers. any idea why ?

Yes. I wrote the original version of that iptables rule set script for a specific application for a specific server. That the server be able to use a web client was not a requirement, nor considered. However, it should work fine. As someone mentioned in the comments, you need to set your interface name and IP address and such.